# Updating Transforms of Attached Nodes in ModelInstance

Tags: java, libgdx

I´m trying to attach a child node to a model I created in libgdx. I used modeBuilder to create a box like this one:

```
       Model model = modelBuilder.createBox(20, 20, 20, new Material(ColorAttribute.createDiffuse(Color.BLUE)),
                VertexAttributes.Usage.Position | VertexAttributes.Usage.Normal);
box = new ModelInstance(model);
box.transform.translate(0, 15, -10);
```

I have a another model I loaded form blender:

```
    Model model;
    model = modelLoader.loadModel(Gdx.files.getFileHandle("crane.g3db", Files.FileType.Internal));
    modelInstance = new ModelInstance(model);
    modelInstance.transform.scale(0.05f, 0.05f, 0.05f);
    modelInstance.transform.translate(0, 0, 500);
    modelInstance.calculateTransforms();
```

Now I´m trying to attach the box as a child of one of the nodes of  the above blender model like this:

```
public void attachBox(int i){
    this.attachedBox = box;
    Node hook = this.modelInstance.getNode("gancho");
    this.attachedBoxNode = this.attachedBox.getNode("node1");
    gancho.addChild(this.attachedBoxNode);
    attachedBoxNode.inheritTransform=true;
    modelInstance.calculateTransforms();
    this.attachedBoxNode.isAnimated = true;


}
```

My question is the following:

What´s the correct way to update the transforms of the node? When I attach the child and set the `inheritTransforms=true;` I´m getting the box scaled and moved around the world. If I set `inheritTransforms=false;`. The box keeps the original size but I´m not able to move it by moving the parent nodes. I want to be able to maintain the size of the box and move it both by moving parent nodes and the box node itself.

Comment: Please define "update the transforms of the node". As you said, if you set `inheritTransforms` to `true` then it will inherit the transform, which it seems like you want to do. What is wrong with that?

Comment: The problem I´m having is that the box is scaling out and moving out of place  at the moment I do `modelInstance.calculateTransforms(); `. For some reason it does not stay in the place I have it before attaching it to the parent node.

Comment: So you want it to inherit the translation but not the scale? You'll have to update the matrix yourself then. "transform" includes both translation and scaling (and rotation), which influence each other btw. It does sound like you are trying to solve the wrong problem though, so you might want to reconsider your approach. But that's not within the scope of your question.

Comment: Thanks for the help @Xoppa. Is there anyway we can chat so you can guide me on the approach I´m taking to solve the problem I´m having?

Comment: I created a chat. I´ll be very helpful if you are able to help me here. I´m a bit confused on the results I´m getting in my code. http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/107438/libgdx

Comment: Try irc://irc.freenode.net/libgdx see also https://github.com/libgdx/libgdx/wiki/Getting-Help